# angular 1.2, how would a router load views without making get calls?

Tags: angularjs

I've been going over the current (angular 1.2.16) routing and multiple views method for angular. Its detailed [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.2/docs/tutorial/step_07). In this we see that for every route there is a get request to load the partial html.

How would I change this so all get requests for views happen when the app instantiates and then the routes switch the views without making further calls to the server?

Comment: AngularJS applications run in a browser.  Where do you envision storing view files? Switching of views involves modifications of the DOM tree.

Comment: Take a look at the template cache... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714690/is-there-a-way-to-preload-templates-and-controllers-when-using-angularjs-routing

Comment: You can use ng-swtich. Instead of pages, wrap the partial content into a div.

Comment: @AnthonyChu you should make that your answer instead of a comment, its a good answer

Comment: @hasH yours is another good idea, why not make it into an answer instead of a comment? I'm interested in this idea of using ng-switch. I'm guess you also meant to lead the partials into the divs using ng-inlcude?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make AngularJS load partials in the beginning and not at when needed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346690/is-there-a-way-to-make-angularjs-load-partials-in-the-beginning-and-not-at-when)

Comment: @andyp - nice find, yes I would agree. But the solution here provided by hasH is not mentioned in the other thread and it is what I was looking for the limited page webapp that I'm building

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that you want to change the content of a div depending on what is stored in `data.mode`. You need to have first a mechanism to change the value of `data.mode` and that's entirely up to you.

```
<div ng-switch on="data.mode">
    <div ng-switch-when="first_value">
        <!--Your first partial page content-->
    </div>

    <div ng-switch-when="second_value">
        <!--Your second partial page-->
    </div>

    <div ng-switch-when="second_value">
        <!--Your third partial page-->
    </div>

    <div ng-switch-default>
        <!--Default content when no match is found.-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfectly unmaintainable !

Comment: Well, yes. But what would you do if your main intention is to reduce the GET calls ?
Your ng-include and ng-view like to hit server everytime.

Comment: There is the templateCache, there is grunt-angular-templates (and similar packages) and there is the `script` directive...

Comment: what if the intention of the user is not to make any get calls for dynamic load ? BTW, thanks for pointing to templateCache.

Comment: 2 out of the 3 solutions I proposed involve 0 additional get calls. Have youeven looked at the script **directive** ?

Comment: Yes. I have. I get your point. I tried to answer the question as per OP's suggestion. I wasn't aware of any of your suggestions. That' how SO makes you learn. Thanks.

Comment: Feel free to investigate those approaches further and update your answer :)

Comment: @ExpertSystem -  templateCache was already mentioned by Anthony Chu. I specifically asked hasH to expand on ng-switch, see comments on main post.

Comment: @PrimeLens: I know you did - I can read comment on main ost :) I just commented that this solution (that hasH proposed in comments and you suggested should be written as an answer and hasH wrote as an answer) is a bad approach for mainatinability reasons (including inability to reuse templates). And then we had a useful conversation where I pointed out some alternatives which I believe hasH found interesting. Finally, I suggested hasH could investigate them more and update their answer (so it does not propose a perfectly unmantainable solution any more).

Comment: @PrimeLens: And I know templateCache was mentioned by Anthony, but it doesn't mean I can't mention it myself (especially since it is a very useful thing). Besides, templateCache alone won't solve any problem - it depends on how you use the templateCache. And since Anthony hadn't added an answer with their suggestion, it would be very useful if someone else did :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do what they suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544558/multiple-ng-view-in-single-template-angular-js) and use  [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

i.e.

```
    <!-- index.html -->
<body>
    <div ui-view="viewA"></div>
    <div ui-view="viewB"></div>
    <!-- Also a way to navigate -->
    <a ui-sref="route1">Route 1</a>
    <a ui-sref="route2">Route 2</a>
</body>
```

Comment: This reminds me of the good old times, when jQuery was the default answer to every javascript question...