# $templateCache, $templateRequest, ngInclude play nice(er) together

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I'm trying to get all my partials at first page view, so that during application viewing no html is downloaded.

### One way is by having templates in `index.html`.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateId.html">
  <p>This is the content of the template</p>
</script>
```

- This way is you have more than 5 templates `index.html` file becomes
  unmanageable and breaks module structure of project.

### Another way of doing this is to have html in `.js` file, most likely in `app.js`

```
myApp.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('templateId.html', 'This is the content of the template');
});
```

- I think `.js` file is no place for html code and again same problems
  as with having it in `index.html`.

---

What I would like to do, is have templates in different files, so I can keep my modules structure and preload them on index.

This is what I have now.

```
var cmsAppFirstRun = function ($templateCache, $templateRequest, $rootScope) {
    $templateRequest('views/common/top-bar.html').then(function (response) {
        $templateCache.put('top.bar', response);
        $rootScope.templatesDone = true;
    });
};

angular.module('cmsApp').run(cmsAppFirstRun);
```

And html

```
<div ng-include="'top.bar'" ng-if="$root.templatesDone"></div>
```

### Is there a more sexy, angularish way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found some techniques using `$http` and `$route` in [stack answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714690/is-there-a-way-to-preload-templates-when-using-angularjs-routing).

I think most appealing is

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
.run(function ($templateCache, $route, $http) {
    var url;
    for(var i in $route.routes)
    {
      if (url = $route.routes[i].templateUrl)
      {
        $http.get(url, {cache: $templateCache});
      }
    }
})
```

This way all templates in route are loaded on first run.

---

EDIT: I'm using [UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) so thing look a bit different in `angular.run()` block. Nested views not handled here yet.

```
angular.forEach($state.get(), function(state){
            if(state.templateUrl){
                $http.get(state.templateUrl, {cache: $templateCache});
            }
        });
```

---

EDIT 2: I've missed $templateRequest that can be path to html template in `angular.run()` block.

```
 $templateRequest('views/cart/modal-confirm-continue-printing.html');
 $templateRequest('views/cart/modal-confirm-trash.html');
```

---

EDIT 3: Since i build applications with grunt, i find https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templates usefoul for automating this process.

Comment: $templateRequest was made for just this situation.  Definitely the best option here.

Comment: I've switched to using https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templates where i can automate process and making less requests on app startup

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if can helps you, but in my project I have used [gulp-ngtemplate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ngtemplate) to generate a js file with all html files as "$templateCache.put()" instruction.

Comment: I use grunt and have since come across some scripts with same functionalities. Will probably update answer with my findings as well.