# Angular 1.5 component $postLink gets triggered too soon in when using templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, components, lifecycle

I followed [this post](https://toddmotto.com/angular-1-5-lifecycle-hooks) to get acquainted with Angular's 1.5 component postLink event.

I got this working in a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vHFVAt). Here's the code for the tabs component:

```
controller: function () {
this.$onInit = function () {
  console.log("$onInit");
  this.tabs = [];
};
this.addTab = function addTab(tab) {
  console.log("addTab");
  this.tabs.push(tab);
};
this.selectTab = function selectTab(index) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.tabs.length; i++) {
    this.tabs[i].selected = false;
  }
  this.tabs[index].selected = true;
};
this.$postLink = function () {
  console.log("$postLink. nr of tabs added: " + this.tabs.length);

  this.selectTab(this.selected);
};
}
```

The console output:

- $onInit
- addTab
- addTab
- addTab
- $postLink. nr of tabs added: 3

However, when I try to do the same in typescript, the postLink event gets triggered too soon. It gets triggered before the tabs can be added to the tabs-component.

Here's some of the code:
/tabs/tab/tab.component.ts

```
namespace MainApp {
const mainApp = angular.module("mainApp");

class TabComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
    public templateUrl: string | ng.Injectable<(...args: any[]) => string>;
    public controller: any;
    public controllerAs: string;
    public transclude: boolean;
    public bindings: any;
    public require: any;

    constructor() {
        this.templateUrl = ["rootUrl", (rootUrl) => rootUrl +  "app/uitrijregelingBerekening/tabs/tab/tab.html"];
        this.controller = TabController;
        this.transclude = true;
        this.bindings = {
            label: "@",
        };
        this.require = {
            tabs: "^^",
        };
    }
}

mainApp.component("tab", new TabComponent());

}
```

/tabs/tab/tab.controller.ts

```
namespace MainApp {
interface ITabBindings {
    label: string;
}

export class TabController implements ITabBindings {
    public label: string;
    private tabs: TabsController;

    public tab: any;

    constructor() {
    }

    public $onInit() {
        this.tab = {
            label: this.label,
            selected: false
        };
        this.tabs.addTab(this.tab);
    }
}
}
```

/tabs/tabs.component.ts

```
namespace MainApp {
const mainApp = angular.module("mainApp");

class TabsComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions{
    public templateUrl: string | ng.Injectable<(...args: any[]) => string>;
    public controller: any;
    public controllerAs: string;
    public bindings: any;
    public transclude: boolean;

    constructor() {
        this.templateUrl = ["rootUrl", (rootUrl) => rootUrl +  "app/uitrijregelingBerekening/tabs/tabs.html"];
        this.controller = TabsController;
        this.bindings = {
            selected:"@",
        };
        this.transclude = true;
    }
}

mainApp.component("tabs", new TabsComponent());

}
```

/tabs/tabs.controller.ts

```
namespace MainApp {
export interface ITabsBindings {
    selected: number;
}

export class TabsController implements ITabsBindings {
    public selected: number;
    public tabs: Array<any>;

    private scope: any;

    static $inject = ["$scope"];
    constructor($scope: ng.IScope) {
        this.scope = $scope;

    }

    public $onInit() {
        console.log("$onInit");
        this.tabs = new Array<any>();
    }

    public addTab(tab: any) {
        console.log("addTab");

        this.tabs.push(tab);
    }

    public selectTab(index: number) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.tabs.length; i++) {
            this.tabs[i].selected = false;
        }
            this.tabs[index].selected = true;
    }

    public $postLink() {
        console.log("$postLink. nr of tabs added: " + this.tabs.length);

        this.selectTab(this.selected);
    }

}
}
```

The templates are the same.

Now the console output is:

- $onInit
- $postLink. nr of tabs added: 0
- angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot set property 'selected' of undefined
- addTab
- addTab
- addTab

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are using a different approach now. Before you just pushed it into an array in one controller. Now you have two components and controllers.

From the Typescript docs, this is your problem.

> ```
>     /**
>      * Called after this controller's element and its children have been linked. Similar to the post-link function this
>      * hook can be used to set up DOM event handlers and do direct DOM manipulation. Note that child elements that contain
>      * templateUrl directives will not have been compiled and linked since they are waiting for their template to load
>      * asynchronously and their own compilation and linking has been suspended until that occurs. This hook can be considered
>      * analogous to the ngAfterViewInit and ngAfterContentInit hooks in Angular 2. Since the compilation process is rather
>      * different in Angular 1 there is no direct mapping and care should be taken when upgrading.
>      */
>     $postLink?(): void;
> ```
>
> **Note that child elements that contain templateUrl directives will not
>   have been compiled and linked since they are waiting for their
>   template to load asynchronously and their own compilation and linking
>   has been suspended until that occurs.**

Instead of using `require` you should maybe bind the `tabs` array to the children.

Comment: In the javascript code I'm also using 2 components and controllers. The setup is basically the same. I'm using require because I want to be able to transclude custom content in the tabs. But the remark about the child elements with templateUrl being loaded asynchronously is the answer here! Indeed, if i switch to literal templates, it works!

Answer (score 1):

@kuhnroyal's answer is the correct one here. But I wanted to post a follow-up because it might be usefull for other people with the same issue. I've managed find a solution which allows me to work with templates in separate files (which improves maintainability), but still use the template-property to guarantee the correct order of postLink events.

I now work with the [`$templateCache`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) object of angular. The key is to preload all the templates when the angular app starts up. And then use the `$templateCache.get` method to fill in the template-property on the components. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714690/is-there-a-way-to-preload-templates-when-using-angularjs-routing) led me to that solution.